# Will adding transaction and rollback to a stored procedure with calls to other stored procedures, work as intended?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure with calls other stored procedures. I want to know if adding transaction and rollback to the stored procedure will work as intended. The inner stored procedures also have transaction and rollbacks

This is for SQL Server 2014

```
ALTER PROCEDURE TemplateBatchDynamicFromRawDataSetTemplateRelnInsert 
    @FileData VARBINARY(MAX) = NULL, 
    @ActualFileName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL, 
    @UserID INT = NULL, 
    @ClientID INT = NULL, 
    @SelectedSheet NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL, 
    @ACAFileNotes NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @ClientTemplateNotes NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @SourceReportFile NVARCHAR(500) = NULL,
    @TemplateIDs INT = 0
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION tr 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @TemplateIDTab as table (TemplateID INT)

        INSERT @TemplateIDTab(TemplateID) 
            EXEC [TemplateFileInsert] 
                 @FileData, @ActualFileName, @UserID, @ClientID, @SelectedSheet, @TemplateIDs

        DECLARE @TemplateID INT = (SELECT TOP 1 TemplateID FROM @TemplateIDTab)

        EXEC [TemplateDetailsInsert] 
             @TemplateID, '', @SourceReportFile, @ClientTemplateNotes, @ACAFileNotes, 3

        SELECT @TemplateID TemplateID
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION tr 

    IF(@@ERROR > 0) 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION tr 
END
GO
```

Comment: Define "work as intended". Error handling in T-SQL is a [really involved topic](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html). To a first approximation, I find that using `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the beginning and using one client-initiated transaction to encapsulate the whole thing is by far the simplest approach. If you must incorporate the error handling in the stored procedures themselves, sit down and take the time to read the linked articles.

Comment: what happens if the caller of this procedure starts its own transaction, and rollbacks where the procedure has commited ?

Comment: @GuidoG: then the whole thing will still roll back, because SQL Server has no notion of nested transactions, and a `COMMIT` while `@@TRANCOUNT` is not 0 effectively has no effect other than decreasing `@@TRANCOUNT`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes exact my point. Thats is why i never do transactions inside procedures

Comment: @GuidoG: Well, it completely depends on your scenario what behavior is actually desired. If the client does not use an explicit transaction, sticking one inside a stored procedure may be *required* to get atomicity. It is neither correct nor incorrect to use a transaction inside an SP, but you do need to be keenly aware of all the rules.

Comment: @JeroenMostert "work as intended" simply means, if an error occurs in the inner storedprocedure and the inner storedprocedure rollbacks, will the outer storedprocedure also rollback?

Comment: It depends on the code of the inner stored procedure, whether it uses `TRY .. CATCH`,  the nature of the error and the value of `XACT_ABORT`. If you were looking for a simple yes/no, I'll have to disappoint you and refer to the link I posted originally. What you have now is probably "too simple" to work reliably in all circumstances.

Comment: Okay @JeroenMostert Thanks a ton.

Comment: @JeroenMostert do you think the below answer would suffice for most of the erroneous situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @JeroenMostert for enlightening me... Keep up the good work. I have updated answer as per our discussion.

After a short read this is what i ended up.. I was a bit short on time.. Please let me know how to improve on it. I was not that keen on raise error part. I just wanted the data to be rolled back correctly.

**OUTER SP**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TemplateBatchDynamicFromRawDataSetTemplateRelnInsert] 
    @FileData VARBINARY(max) = NULL, 
    @ActualFileName NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
    @UserID INT = NULL, 
    @ClientID INT = NULL, 
    @SelectedSheet NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
    @ACAFileNotes NVARCHAR(max) = NULL,
    @ClientTemplateNotes NVARCHAR(max) = NULL,
    @SourceReportFile NVARCHAR(500) = NULL,
    @IncludedInDataSet bit = 0,
    @TemplateID INT =0 
AS
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION tr 
    BEGIN 
    DECLARE @retTemplateID INT
    EXEC [TemplateFileInsert] @FileData,@ActualFileName,@UserID,@ClientID,@SelectedSheet,@TemplateIDs = @TemplateID OUTPUT

    EXEC [TemplateDetailsInsert] @TemplateID,'',@SourceReportFile,@ClientTemplateNotes,@ACAFileNotes ,3,@IncludedInDataSet

    EXEC [dbo].[TemplateBatchDetailsByTemplateIDSelect] @TemplateID
    --SELECT @TemplateID TemplateID
    END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION tr 

END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   ; THROW
    END CATCH
```

**INNER SP**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TemplateDetailsInsert] 
      @TemplateID INT =0 ,
      @TemplateName NVARCHAR(500) = NULL, 
      @SourceReportFile NVARCHAR(500) = NULL, 
      @ClientTemplateNotes NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
      @ACAFileNotes NVARCHAR(max) = NULL,
      @DataSourceID INT = NULL,
      @IncludedInDataSet bit = 0
    AS 

    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @trancount BIT = 0
        BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        IF(@DataSourceID = 3)
        BEGIN
            EXEC TemplateNameCreator @TemplateID,@TemplateName out

            UPDATE [TemplateBatch] 
            SET 
            TemplateName = @TemplateName, 
            [SourceReportFile] = @SourceReportFile , 
            ClientTemplateNotes=@ClientTemplateNotes,
            ACAFileNotes = @ACAFileNotes, 
            DataSourceID = @DataSourceID,
            IncludedInDataSet = ISNULL(NULLIF(@IncludedInDataSet,0),IncludedInDataSet)
            WHERE TemplateID = @TemplateID
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [TemplateBatch] SET TemplateName = @TemplateName, [SourceReportFile] = @SourceReportFile , ClientTemplateNotes=@ClientTemplateNotes,
            ACAFileNotes = @ACAFileNotes, DataSourceID = @DataSourceID
            WHERE TemplateID = @TemplateID
        END

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
     ; THROW
    END CATCH
```

Comment: @JeroenMostert do you think this would suffice for most of the erroneous situations?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the inner SP check for an active transaction and optionally start one. It can just begin one unconditionally. SQL Server has no true nested transactions, but the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` / `COMMIT` in the inner proc will just cancel out. Note that trying to avoid rolling back the whole transaction in the inner proc to "save" the outer transaction is mostly pointless -- if an error happens that dooms the transaction, a rollback is unavoidable anyway.

Comment: Hi @JeroenMostert. The check for trancount for rolling back is un-necessary i agree, but i wanted the trancount check for commiting. I'll update the answer. Thank you. Is there any other updates you would do to this?

Comment: You misunderstand -- doing a check of `@@TRANCOUNT` for the rollback *is* necessary, because the engine may or may not have rolled back the transaction implicitly, and doing a `ROLLBACK` if the transaction is already dead is itself an error. So always do `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK`. What is unnecessary is the whole `IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 BEGIN TRANSACTION` -- you can write the inner procedure exactly like the outer procedure. The behavior doesn't need to be different depending on whether it's called on its own or nested.

Comment: Hi @JeroenMostert sorry for the misunderstanding. But, i want the inner sp to be rolled back if an error happens in the outer sp. So will adding a transaction in the inner sp and committing it, cause a hindrance? So because of this doubt only if the inner sp is called directly (trancount == 0) there will be a transaction and commit. can u tell me what should i do for the desired behavior? PS. I have added the IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK

Comment: No, it will not hinder anything. The `BEGIN TRANSACTION` / `COMMIT` will simply increase `@@TRANCOUNT` and then decrease it again. The data in the inner SP is *not* actually committed unless and until the *outer* SP commits. If the outer SP rolls back, all the statements of the inner SP will also be rolled back. SQL Server has no notion of true nested transaction or "intermediate" commits, so committing an "inner" transaction has no actual effect.

Comment: @JeroenMostert i have updated the sp as per our discussion. Thank you for all the help. It is hard to find people like you these days. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

**In above example...
@outTes output parameter in both procedures to check if the inner procedure fails, to be able to decide to do a ROLLBACK or not. Now execution of the innerProc procedure will not generate an error and rollback transcation will happen..**

So...you can try this.....

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code. You can use the `{}` button (or press Ctrl-K) to format code snippets.